# Creating a worksheet and automated solutions

Tags: formatting, exam

Unfortunately, most codes I see on forums are far too complex for me that address this topic.

However, does one know whether there is an easy way to generate a worksheet with latex (for pupils) that shows the solutions automatically on the next page? 
Is there a way to put the code for each solution below each coded task in the .tex? (I hope I made myself clear, if not I will rephrase it).

The worksheet would be for a language class.

Thank you,

Comment: If you could add a MWE or, at least, an example or template you're going to use for your worksheets, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: The [exam package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) or [exsheets](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf) package sounds like it can do what you are asking. You might try searching CTAN for other packages. Searching on "exam" gets you [this](https://www.ctan.org/topic/exam) large list of packages to look at.

Comment: see also https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/

Answer (score 1):

A simple package for exercises with delayed answers is `exercise`.

Since you're writing it for pupils, you may use TikZlings, too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeaderNB}{\tikz[scale=.7]{\tikzling[
  signpost={\textcolor{blue}{\theExercise}},
  signcolour=red,
  signback=pink
  ]}}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Solution to exercise}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent\bfseries\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB:~}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
    \begin{Exercise}    
    {\itshape Cats \tikz[scale=.2]{\cat} eat ducks \tikz[scale=.2]{\duck}}
        
        Which is the subject?
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}
        Cats.
    \end{Answer}
    \begin{Exercise}
    {\itshape Cats \tikz[scale=.2]{\cat[body=red]} eat ducks \tikz[scale=.2]{\duck[pizza]}}
    
        
        Which is the object?
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}
        Ducks.
    \end{Answer}
    \begin{Exercise}
        {\itshape Ducks \tikz[scale=.2]{\duck[glasses]} don't like cats \tikz[scale=.2]{\cat[body=blue]}}
        
        Which is the verb?
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}
        Don't like.
    \end{Answer}
    \newpage
\section{Answers}
    \shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

[image]